# Use variable as part of textbox name in C#

Tags: c#, variables, object, loops, textbox

I am developing a program wth 30 text boxes and 30 check boxes next to them. I want people to check names and then press the send button. The program then saves the names in a txt file with a true or false statement next to them, it then uploads the file to a ftp server for me analize.
The problem I am facing is that I don't want to write code for every text and check box to load and save it's value on the txt file.
If I name the text boxes something like tbox1;tbox2;tbox3 etc. How would use a loop to say write the value of tbox *i* + ; + cbox *i* on line *i* of thing.txt or vice versa?
Please any help would be grately apreciated because this will save me a lot of unnesacery code writing!

Comment: use repeater or any other control that allows you to replicate UI

Comment: If you can use jquery - check out http://sushantp.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/jquery-get-the-checked-and-unchecked-items-from-list-of-checkboxes/. This allows you to easily get the list of checked (or unchecked) checkboxes from a page.

Comment: Thanks this looks great but have not lerned very far in this language so this is still a bit above me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            TextBox textbox = (TextBox)Controls.Find(string.Format("tbox{0}", i),false).FirstOrDefault();
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)Controls.Find(string.Format("cbox{0}", i),false).FirstOrDefault();

            string s = textbox.Text + (checkbox.Checked ? "true" : "false");
        }
```

Comment: sorry, there was no IDE in that moment.

Comment: Thanks this is just what I need but thanks to all of you who gave me responses!

Answer (score 4):

You should create a `List<TextBox>`, and populate it with your textboxes in the constructor.

You can then loop through the list and process the textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all the controls on your form and retrieve the values from them based on their type/name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is ASP.NET, you could use something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 1; i < 30; i++){
    TextBox tb = FindControl("TextBox" + i);
    Checkbox cb = FindControl("CheckBox" + i);
    sb.AppendFormat("TextBox{0}={1}; {2}", i, tb.Text, cb.Checked);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
// Now write 'result' to your text file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through controls in your form/control and investigate name:

```
        foreach (Control control in f.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
               //Investigate and do your thing
            }
        }
```